# PowerShell: why does "Get-Content <file> | Out-File -Append <file>" go into a loop?

Tags: powershell

I understand why the following will truncate the contents of the file:

```
Get-Content <file> | Out-File <file>
```

This is because Out-File is run first and it empties the file before Get-Content has a chance to read it.

But when I try a variant of the above, it goes into a loop:

```
Get-Content <file> | Out-File -Append <file>
```

If I break the loop and examine the file, I see the initial contents are repeated over and over. Could anyone explain why this is happening?

I would have expected the contents of the file to be repeated twice not that it goes into a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get-Content gives you content line by line, Append adds 1 line from the pipeline to the end of file. So for every line you encounter, a line gets added to the end. So - it never ends. If you expect to have your contents repeated twice, read the whole file into a variable, append it to itself, and then output your results to a file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that append adds 1 line and the pipeline will terminate? Here it seems like append adds 1 line and the pipeline starts over ...

Comment: @RakheshSasidharan: It does not start over, it just never has a chance to finish. After adding line #1, it will advance to line #2 as soon as Get-Content reads it. Like I said, Get-Content will be eating lines 1 by 1 regardless of how the file changes, as long as it still exists. Out-File -Append does not care either, as long as Get-Content keeps supplying it with input. Problem is that Out-File is giving more work to Get-Content, which in turn gives more work to itself. So these two commands keep each other busy.